# Mouse input transparency in Qt without visual transparency

Tags: c++, qt, input, mouseevent

I know of [`Qt::WindowTransparentForInput`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html) which makes a window and all of its chilren transparent, and [`QWidget::mask`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregion.html) which also visually clips the region outside. I want to draw a window with client side shadows, so I need mouse input- but not visual transparency. How is this possible?

Comment: It wasn't possible last time I investigated that a couple of years ago. If I understand correctly, you want your app to be more of an overlay but pass events through. You will probably have to dig into the OS APIs to do that. Although the input event system has been revamped quite a lot and my use case was a bit more specific. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52803057/qt-selectively-allow-a-click-to-fall-through-to-a-lower-application-window

Comment: If I were a window manager, i would not really want to allow this feature, since it facilitates [clickjacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking).

Comment: @Davidvanrijn yet every window manager seems to allow it, otherwise it would be impossible to have any application that needs to be an overlay,

Comment: What if you paint your shadow into separate windows with `Qt::WindowTransparentForInput`?

Comment: Does `Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents` help?

Comment: When enabled, this attribute disables the delivery of mouse events to the widget **and its children.**